# How do I create an arbitrary theano tensor given a dtype and a shape?

Tags: python, theano

How do I create an arbitrary theano tensor given a dtype and a shape?  I would rather not make a big switch for the length of the shape and kind of dtype.

```
import numpy as np
from theano import tensor


def arbitrary_tensor(dtype, shape, name=None):
    function = {
        np.float32: 'f',
        np.float64: 'd',
        np.int8: 'b',
        np.int16: 'w',
        np.int32: 'i',
        np.int64: 'l',
        np.complex64: 'c',
        np.complex128: 'z',
    }[dtype]

    function += {
        0: 'scalar',
        1: 'vector',
        2: 'matrix',
        3: 'tensor3',
        4: 'tensor4'}[len(shape)]

    return getattr(tensor, function)(name=name)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `theano.tensor.TensorType(dtype, broadcastable)`

The dtype is a numpy dtype string and broadcastable is a list of booleans specifying if the dimension is broadcastable or not.

An example of your function would be:

```
def arbitrary_tensor(dtype, shape, name=None):
    # create the type.
    var_type = theano.tensor.TensorType(
        dtype=dtype,
        broadcastable=[False]*len(shape))

    # create the variable from the type.
    return var_type(name)
```

Except that `dtype` here should be a string like `'float32'`, not a numpy object like `np.float32`.  If you absolutely must use numpy objects then you'll have to map them to strings.